# Cannot find module 'webpack' using webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Trying to get familiar to chat apps using [this](https://nolanprice.com/post/typescript-react-redux-chat/) tutorial.

Everything looks good, but when I try to run `npm run watch` according to the directions in the end, I get an error with npm, mentioning the error is not with npm.

This `watch` script was created to run the following script:

```
webpack-dev-server --compress --history-api-fallback --progress --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3005
```

When I try to run this line using `npx`, I get the following error:

```
Cannot find module 'webpack'
Require stack:
- /home/user/.npm/_npx/47997/lib/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js
```

This is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  output: {
    filename: './build/client.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [{ test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }]
  }
};
```

I have tried to install `webpack` and `webpack-cli` a couple of times, and it did not correct the error. Tried to delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and then reinstall the modules, and nothing happened as well. Any suggestions?

Adding `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "rcweb",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "rcweb",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "webpack-dev-server --compress --history-api-fallback --progress --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3005"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.17",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3",
    "webpack": "^5.24.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev": "^1.1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Provide your `package.json`, please.

Comment: I think you need to install webpack-cli, and webpack-dev-server. You can try put "npx" before the command as well.

Comment: @zhulien edited to add Package.json

Comment: `webpack` is listed as a peer dependency, so `npx` should work with `npm@^7.0.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install `webpack-dev-server` instead of `webpack-dev`. Update your `package.json` then delete your `node_modules` and `npm install` everything anew.

Also, I am not sure it is a very good idea to use react and related components as `devDependencies` as they're used in runtime, but it depends on your bundle build and configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, as per Package.json I think it was missing to install webpack-dev-server.

After I've done that, the error changed:

```
Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
```

Reading a bit about it, some topics mentioned versions, but I believe all webpack components are on the latest:

```
webpack 5.24.4
webpack-cli 4.5.0
webpack-dev-server 3.11.2
```

Still have this issue to go...